# Combinatorics - Harvard Math Tournament.

Tags: combinatorics

For positive integers $x$, let $g(x)$ be the number of blocks of consecutive $1$’s in the binary expansion of
$x$. For example, $g(19) = 2$ because $19 = 10011_2$ has a block of one $1$ at the beginning and a block
of two $1$’s at the end, and $g(7) = 1$ because $7 = 111_2$ only has a single block of three $1$’s. Compute
$g(1) + g(2) + g(3) + \cdots + g(256)$.

My try:

[image]

Original Solution:

http://hmmt.mit.edu/static/archive/february/solutions/2015/combo.pdf

I understand the solution posted by HMMT.  I solved it differently.  The rationale for this solution is the combin formula represents a flip from $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $0$ in all binary sequences generated segregated by no of binary digits of the decimal numbers according to digits.

My general question, I try to solve such problems using patterns that you can discern from working out first few numbers and identify that and extend it to higher order numbers.  Considering this to be a tournament problem, I am amazed at people who solve using the method given in the original solution.  I am suspecting that such skill is possible only having encountered this problem or is that there are sharks who are really geniuses out there. Can someone tell me if I am living in a small pond with not much exposure to sharks that might be living elsewhere!!!

Comment: "My general question..." can you clarify, what is the point? IMHO, HMMT must provide a solution so one can see the problem is actually *solvable*. It is not required to HMMT to provide a solution, *reachable* in the given amount of time or power.

Comment: My question may seem stupid, but I really was wondering if you could solve such problems in the method provided by HMMT at a tournament and if people could solve,  have they encountered similar problems before.

Comment: My solution (exactly the first idea) would be to provide a recurrence relation on $f(b,k) =$ sum of $g(x)$ over such $x$ that binary representation of $x$ starts with digit $b$ and is exactly $k$ digits long. Another idea is to break $0\dots 255$ into $2$ non-overlapping classes or to use a bijection e.g. $1$'s complement. I did not open the link above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly reasonable. Note that you don’t have to do all of the arithmetic: ignoring $g(256)$, you have

$$\sum_{k=1}^4k\binom9{2k}=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^42k\binom9{2k}=\frac92\sum_{k=1}^4\binom8{2k-1}=\frac92\cdot2^7=9\cdot2^6=576\;.$$

The second step uses the identity $k\binom{n}k=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$, and the third uses the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^4\binom8{2k-1}$ is just the number of odd-sized subsets of an $8$ element set, which is half of $2^8$, the total number of subsets.

I’ve not looked at the PDF, but another approach that occurs to me is to notice that apart from $256$, we’re looking at the positive integers that can be written with $8$ binary digits, allowing leading zeroes. Each of those binary representations can be divided into alternating blocks of zeroes and ones, and the sum of the lengths of the blocks is evidently $8$. Thus, we’re looking at [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $8$.

Consider, as an example, the composition $8=3+2+1+2$. This corresponds to the two binary numbers $00011011$ and $11100100$. In the latter the first and third parts are the lengths of blocks of ones, and in the former the second and fourth parts are the lengths of blocks of ones. Every composition of $8$ is going to behave like this: it will correspond to two complementary strings of $8$ bits, and each of its parts will be the length of a block of ones in exactly one of those two strings. In particular, in these two bit strings combined we have one block of ones for each part of the composition. It follows that $\sum_{k=1}^{255}g(k)$ is the total number of parts in all compositions of $8$, and adding $1$ to this will yield the desired result.

Let $a_n$ be the total number of parts in all compositions of $n$. It’s well-known (and [not hard to prove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29#Number_of_compositions)) that $n$ has $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ compositions with exactly $k$ parts, so

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n-1}{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\binom{n-1}k+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k\\
&=(n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-2}{k-1}+2^{n-1}\\
&=(n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}k+2^{n-1}\\
&=(n-1)2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}\\
&=(n+1)2^{n-2}\;.
\end{align*}$$

This is a bit more elegant, but if confronted with the problem under time pressure, I’m fairly sure that I could come up with and complete your solution faster than this one.

---

I’ve now looked at the PDF. Its first solution also uses the idea of looking at complementary pairs of bit strings, but it does so in a very different way and is more efficient; of the four solutions that I’ve seen it strikes me as the one requiring the most cleverness to come up with. Its second solution is really a pretty straightforward counting argument, similar to the arguments used to come up with many recurrences involving strings of symbols; I’m mildly embarrassed that I didn’t see it and would not be at all surprised to see a contestant come up with it.

But to answer your final question, there are indeed some pretty impressive sharks out there.

Comment: Thanks Dr Scott.Nice one!!!

Comment: @satisfy: You're welcome.